# Facebook Android Login not working how it should be

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

So my Facebook Login for my android App isn't working how it should be.

Basically I click on the LoginButton and it forwards be to login. When I hit the return button on my device and try and click the Login Button, the Login Window isn't shown again.

Not sure how to get around this?
Must be something I'm doing wrong?

Mainifest file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.ac.tees.parse_fbintergration_example1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:maxSdkVersion="21"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Parse_FBIntergration_Example1</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="facebook_app_id">*FB_ID_HIDDEN*</string>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    private MainFragment frag;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            frag = new MainFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
        } else {
            frag = (MainFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



 public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);



        loginBtn = (LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginBtn.setFragment(this);
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the my example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128858/facebook-login-from-custom-ui-in-android/29128990

Comment: @MaksHameliak You're a superstar, thanks bud!

Answer (score 1):

Your Mainfest.xml file is correct. I am assuming your using facebook sdk 4.0 and on.

You need to add a fragment and inflate a layout having Facebook Login button.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

And in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
   callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_likes", "user_friends");
   loginButton.setFragment(this);

   loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        //Handle your success result here
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook_login, container, false);
   return view;
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I got it sorted. I'll up vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
      **Process Login With Facebook**
        **Working on Play Store** 

    **Link 

 - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codecube.airbucks&hl=en

**



            Registered your new app? If you didn't, go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, click Add a New App in the top right and follow the instructions. **step by step**

            **Manifest Permission**
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

            **build.Gradle Dependency**
            compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'  // in airbuck

                /*compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'*/


             <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                        android:label="@string/app_name" />
                    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
                        android:value="@string/app_name" />
                    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

                    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1854328631556764"
                        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                        android:exported="true"/> 

        **Layout Xml Code**
        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        **Put own generate facebook Key in String.xml File** 
        <string name="facebook_app_id">1854328631556764</string>
            <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb1854328631556764</string>

            **MainActivity CODE**
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
                    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
                    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);   

                    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                    fbloginButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);


                    fbloginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                                            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                                    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        //showing dialog to select image
                                        callFacebook();
                                        Log.e("permission", "granted");
                                    } else {
                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    callFacebook();
                                }
                        }
                    });
                }

             **CAllOnFAcebook**
                public void callFacebook() {

                    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            //        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity2.this, Arrays.asList("email"));

                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

                    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            Log.e("keshav","onSuccess called ");
                            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                JSONObject object,
                                                GraphResponse response) {
                                            // Application code
                                            Log.v("LoginActivityfacebook", response.toString());

                                            try {
                                                JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                                facebookName = data.getString("name");
                                                facebookEmail = data.getString("email");
                                                facebookId = data.getString("id");
                                                facebookLink = data.getString("link");
                                                facebookLink = facebookLink.replace("https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/", "");
                                                facebookLink = facebookLink.replace("/", "");
                                                Log.e("profilelink", "" + facebookLink);
                                                facebookLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookLink + "/picture";

                                                Log.e("facebookName", "is  ->  " + facebookName);
                                                Log.e("facebookEmail", "is  ->  " + facebookEmail);
                                                Log.e("facebookId", "is  ->  " + facebookId);
                                                Log.e("facebookLink", "is  ->  " + facebookLink);


                                                    Log.e("Keshav","Suceesfully Login "+facebookName);



                                                } else {
                                                    CommonMethod.showAlert("Intenet Connectivity Failure", MainActivity.this);
                                                }
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,link");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // App code
                            Log.i(TAG, "cancelTriggered");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                            // App code
                            Log.i(TAG, "errorTriggered");
                        }
                    });
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();                //  TODO Add Me Using this previous facebook login id password logout
                }


            **Process Login With Facebook**
        **Working on Play Store** 

    **Link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codecube.airbucks&hl=en**
```